# RecordMyDesktop doesn't work. Suggestions for a screen recorders for my game console?

Tags: 12.04

Please. I need a new screen recorder so I can record my emulated games. (PS1, SNES)
Please suggest me ones that are simple and require no hard to understand `sudo` code.

Comment: By game console, I meant emulators.

Answer (score 0):

I often use RecordMyDesktop without any problem, open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, enter `recordmydesktop`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and your screen recording will be started. Just go back to the terminal and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop recording, then wait for the file to be created.

"Doesn't work" is not a valid error message, what's your real problem?

Comment: I play the video, after a view minutes of bandwidth have passed, my mic either cuts off, or the video stays on 1 single frame and doesn't move from there on in.

Answer (score 0):

What about [SimpleScreenRecorder](http://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/)? I have never used this for gaming, but I think it works really well in general. It can record a fixed rectangle which is what I assume you want. (It also looks a lot better nowadays compared to the screenshots on the website)

Comment: Umm, SimpleScreenRecorder requires me to use code, and make directories. so, not to SSR.